# ora2pg fails to connect but sqlplus works

Tags: oracle, ora2pg

I am using the setup from `https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/minimum-viable-oracle-database-19c-installation-on-ol8#download-software` that does this:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
alter session set container=ORCLPDB1;

create user testuser1 identified by testuser1 quota unlimited on users;
grant connect, resource to testuser1;

exit;
EOF
```

Login to the DB is successful with:

```
sqlplus testuser1/testuser1@//localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1
```

But with an `ora2pg.conf` file set up thusly:

```
ORACLE_DSN      dbi:Oracle:host=localhost;service_name=ORCLCDB;port=1521
ORACLE_USER     testuser1
ORACLE_PWD      testuser1
```

...I fail to login.  I have tried

1. Changing the DSN and it properly says it cannot find the database at all; good
2. Changing the service_name and it says no such service exists; good
3. Trying both `service_name=ORCLCDB` (as it appears in `tnsnames.ora`) and `service_name=ORCLCDB1` in the `ORACLE_DSN`.  `ORCLCDB` waits for a bit then fails; `ORCLCDB1` fails fast with:

```
FATAL: 12514 ... ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)
```

The `ora2pg.conf` is a copy from the dist version with just DNS, USER, and PWD changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service name of your pluggable database is `ORCLPDB1`, so use it instead of CDB service name(`ORCLCDB`):

```
ORACLE_DSN      dbi:Oracle:host=localhost;service_name=ORCLPDB1;port=1521
ORACLE_USER     testuser1
ORACLE_PWD      testuser1
```

Comment: Tried that; apols, did not put it into orig question.   Updating now.

Comment: ORCL*P*DB1, not `ORCLCDB1 fails fast with`

Comment: ie `P` instead of `C`